# sklearn TimeSeriesSplit Error: KeyError: '[ 0 1 2 ...] not in index'

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, sklearn-pandas, train-test-split

I want to use TimeSeriesSplit from sklearn on the following dataframe to predict sum:
[image: dataframe]

So to prepare X and y I do the following:

```
X = df.drop(['sum'],axis=1)
y = df['sum']
```

and then feed these two to:

```
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
X_train01, X_test01 = X[train_index], X[test_index]
y_train01, y_test01 = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

by doing so, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: '[ 0  1  2 ...] not in index'
```

Here X is a dataframe, and apparently this cause the error, because if I convert X to an array as following:

```
X = X.values
```

Then it will work. However, for later evaluation of the model I need X as a dataframe. Is there any way that I can keep X as a dataframe and feed it to tscv without converting it to an array?

Comment: I'm confused by `tscv.split(X)` and what type `tscv` object is. It seems like you have a time index and you are trying to select indices by integers. Try `iloc` instead?

Answer (score 8):

As @Jarad rightly said, if you have updated version of pandas, it will not automatically switch to integer based indexing as was possible in previous versions. You need to explicitly use `.iloc` for integer based slicing.

```
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    X_train01, X_test01 = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train01, y_test01 = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html